# asp.net button not working or firing no postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a asp.net button on my page
Clicking on the button does not seem to get to the code
I've tried setting the causes validation to false with no joy
I've set a breakpoint on the code behind but it never gets there.
This actually was working when I initally setup the button not sure why this has now stopped.
I'm using an update panel further up the page as well but its outside the content of this button

when attempting a click it looks like postback doesnt even get initiated

```
                <asp:Button ID="btnRadioStatus" 
                    runat="server" 
                    OnClick="btnRadioStatus_Click" 
                    Text="Online Radio Status" 
                    Font-Size="Large" 
                    Width="40%" 
                    Height="300px" CausesValidation="false" 
                  />
```

Code behind is

```
 protected void btnRadioStatus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            using (var client = new SshClient("172.16.0.54", "test", "test"))
            {
                client.Connect();
                client.Disconnect();

            }
        }
```

Nothing much in page load except for some checks

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



            //check for daylight saving time
            dayLightSavingCheckAdjust();

            ReadMyData();



            System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = null;
            // Dim files() As System.IO.FileInfo 'array of fileinfo objects


            //get the specified directory
            dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo("Images\\hadiths");


            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("Images/hadiths/"));



            foreach (string str in files)
            {

                ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("imgfileName", "'" + Path.GetFileName(str) + "'");

            }
            checkRadioStatus();  //check is radio is online 

        }
```

the checkRadioStatus just checks for the mic and changes the text and backcolour

```
  public void checkRadioStatus()
        {

            using (var client = new SshClient("172.16.0.54", "test", "test"))
            {
                client.Connect();
                SshCommand strMicStatus = client.RunCommand(@"sudo amixer -c1 get Mic | grep Mono: | awk '{print $6}' | sed 's/\[//g;s/\]//g'");

                //  Console.WriteLine(strMicStatus);

                client.Disconnect();

                if (strMicStatus.Result == "on\n")
                {
                    btnRadioStatus.Text = "Radio is Online";
                    btnRadioStatus.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                }

                else
                {
                    btnRadioStatus.Text = "Radio is Offline";
                    btnRadioStatus.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Olive;
                }
            }


        }
```

Comment: Are other buttons / controls on your webpage working fine?

Comment: Also, why do you think your button isn't working? Have you tried debugging or printing a message to the client upon the event execution?

Comment: Do you see any console errors ?

Comment: Dont have any other asp.net buttons etc on my page expect for some jquery which is working fine.

Comment: no console errors

Comment: So the button doesnt even flex downwards when clicking its as if its disabled

Comment: @AShah any page_load code?

Comment: does your breakpoint hits at all?

Comment: added page load - nothing here apart from some checks

Comment: breakpoint doesnt hit - the button doesnt even flex downwards!

Comment: inspect its client-side runtime attributes - is it disabled?

Comment: from client side --->>> <input type="submit" name="btnRadioStatus1" value="Radio is Online" id="btnRadioStatus1" style="background-color:Red;">

Comment: @AShah what is Radiostatus method in page_load

Comment: @webruster - added above

Comment: Also setting this up on another clean page I've noticed the icon doesn't change to the finger when hovering over the control

Comment: @AShah why are u using causevalidation , are you using server side validation? if not try to remove and verify once

Comment: I just put that it to troubleshoot it doesnt work even with it removed

Answer (score 0):

Resolved my css for the div had a zindex of - 1